# Missing Files in Vagrant Synced Folder Path

Tags: macos, vagrant, virtualbox, homestead

My installation of vagrant is not seeing every file within the synced folder path.

From my Mac shell:

```
my-mac:seeds pivot$ ls -la BeltContentP*Seeds.php
-rw-rw-r--  1 pivot  staff  3034 Dec  7 11:21 BeltContentPageSeeds.php
-rw-rw-r--  1 pivot  staff  1627 Dec  6 16:54 BeltContentPostSeeds.php
```

From my Vagrant shell:

```
vagrant@homestead:~/Code/demo.larabelt/all/database/seeds$ ls -la BeltContentP*Seeds.php
-rw-r--r-- 1 vagrant vagrant 1627 Dec  6 21:54 BeltContentPostSeeds.php
```

If I rename the missing file in my host system, it appears on my guest.

This issue appeared after upgrading my Mac OS to High Sierra 10.13.1. I had otherwise used this setup successfully for probably 2+ years.

I have since tried to upgrade the various related packages, as well as reinstalling various items, but it has not solved the issue so far. Downgrading my Mac OS to the previous version does not appear to be easy or straightforward.

Additional Detail:
 - sync type: NFS
 - VirtualBox: 5.1.30
 - Vagrant: 2.0.1
 - Vagrant Box: laravel/homestead
 - Vagrant Plugins: 'vagrant-bindfs' & 'vagrant-vbguest'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mac OS High Sierra broke NFS file sharing pretty hard. See https://github.com/hashicorp/vagrant/issues/8788 but this should be resolved via MacOS 10.13.2 Have you updated yet today? That *should* resolve the issue for you.

Comment: I wasn't aware they had published 10.13.2. I had checked multiple times today and it said I was up to date. After some clicking around, it refreshed the list and then 10.13.2 showed up. Thanks.